# Função imagecreatefromgif não pega

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar essa função mas não sei se estou usando da forma correta queria saber oque estou errando

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
?>
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/GIF");
?>

<?php

$img = imagecreatefromgif("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/657537129241825280/9vpxbnIi_normal.png");

ImageGif ($img);    

?>
```

Estou usando a função assim mas não pega, essa imagem que eu botei é só um exemplo porque eu vou pegar os dados vindo de uma variável depois pra montar a imagem.

OBS: O Erro que da é que fica só uma imagem quadrada tipo de erro aparecendo.

Comment: Não o que? não falta um echo no final? o que (não) acontece?

Comment: O Erro que da é que fica só uma imagem quadrada tipo de erro aparecendo.

Comment: Nem botando echo não aparece a imagem gerada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não pega porque a imagem do link é PNG e você está usando a função para pegá-la em GIF.

Depois de pegar você pode convertê-la em GIF.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/gif");

$img = imagecreatefrompng("http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/657537129241825280/9vpxbnIi_normal.png");

imagegif ($img);

?>
```

Comment: Só fiquei com uma duvida agora e se a imagem que eu usar for assim,

Comment: Tentei bota imagecreatefromgif - imagecreatefromjpeg - imagecreatefrompng e nada oque pode ser?

Comment: Acontece isso porquê a imagem é criada por um script também. Não sei no momento resgatar a imagem quando a situação é essa.